# Select audio added via new Audio

Tags: javascript

We can pause all audios that have an audio tag using this code:

```
const sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
sounds.forEach(sound => sound.pause());
```

In the above code, we can select all the audio tags and do whatever we want on them.

The issue is if we create audio using `new Audio` there will be no audio tag on the DOM and we can't select the audio...

Here is the code I try:

```
setTimeout(() => play(), 3000);

function play(){
  const prefixAudio = new Audio(`audio.mp3`);
  prefixAudio.play();
}
```

How can I select this audio so that I can pause it? How can I select audios added via this method?

Comment: Put the `prefixAudio` in the global scope for the `play` and  other functions

Comment: It doesn't add the audio to DOM..

Comment: Are you using right path in the audio `constructor` function

Comment: and most modern browsers will block `autoplay` or play without user interections, so be careful there

Answer (score 1):

```
const prefixAudio = new Audio(`audio.mp3`);

const play = () => {
  prefixAudio.play();
}

const pause = () => {
  prefixAudio.pause();
}
    setTimeout(() => play(), 3000);
```

Like this?